# In WPF, how can I set a TextBox MaxHeight according to Two other controls

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, converters

I have the following Structure:

```
            <StackPanel
                Name="stkOuter">
                <StackPanel
                    Name="stkInner">
                    Content...
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBox>
                    Content...
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
```

I need to set MaxHeight for the TextBox as

```
           stkOuter.ActualHeight-stkInner.ActualHeight
```

But a converter can only take one parameter using Binding, and the ConverterParameter must be an object.

```
MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, 
                    Path=ActualHeight, 
                    Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, 
                    ConverterParameter={WHAT GOES HERE?}}"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You must use an IMultiValueConverter:

```
<TextBox.MaxHeight>
   <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource myIMultiValueConverter}>
      <Binding /> <!-- bind the first value here -->
      <Binding /> <!-- bind the second value here -->
      ...
   </MultiBinding>
</TextBox.MaxHeight>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) instead of a simple `Binding`; that will allow your converter to operate on multiple input values which can all be produced through binding (`ConverterParameter` cannot take its value from a `Binding`).